# Notepad++ remove 4 digit numbers with blank lines on either sides

Tags: notepad++

Hi I want to remove > 2000 page numbers in a txt file.
I want to find the 4 digit numbers (Eg: 1198) using regular expression in notepad++

I have tried ^\r\n^(\d{4})\n^\r\n which did not work. Any advice please. Many thanks.

eg:

19/10/2018  CCHAPC      C        06/06/1949  10168259 RRKK323224 454 909 1339

1198

21/10/2018  CCHES       C        19/05/1946  10034850 RRKS589180 490 589 4964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `\R` to match any unicode newline sequence:

```
^\R\d{4}\R{2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fdj9aW/1)

Or with the newline and optional carriage return, and the capturing group:

```
^\r?\n(\d{4})\r?\n\r?\n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oWJDZm/1)

[image]